# javascript highlight a string

Tags: javascript

`var str = 'test TEST';`

How to get `str` = '`<span class="red">test</span> <span class="red">TEST</span>`' in return.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since the spaces won't show up as red, there's no real difference between <span class="red">test Test</span> and your result? Why not just wrap the string with the span stuff?

Comment: if string is `test love test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work for words composed of characters matched by `\w`, which are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _. This means, for example, that it will fail for words containing accented characters, but will work fine for your example.

```
var str = 'test TEST';
var highlighted = str.replace(/([\w]+)/g, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
str.replace(/(\w+) (\w+)/, '<span class="red">$1</span> <span class="red">$2</span>')
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all fancy with REGEX and such but it is just a simple string replace.

```
var tt = "<span class='red'>test</span>"
var TT = "<span class='red'>TEST</span>"

str = str.replace("test", tt).replace("TEST", TT);
```